# sending long sms using php (not using external api), texts getting lost

Tags: php, email, loops, sms

I have the basic functionality down, but I'm trying to allow the user to send text messages longer than 160 chars

I get a string and split it by char length.  Then I use mail to send my string.  I put a delay in there in case texts are being lost due to the speed they are being sent.

```
        $string =  "Area: {$post['area']}\r\nMessage Type: {$post['messageType']}\r\nOutage Type: {$post['outageType']}\r\nDescription: {$post['description']}\r\nTroubleshooting: {$post['troubleshooting']}\r\n";
        $splittedString = str_split($string, 140);
        foreach($members as $member){
            foreach($splittedString as $splitStrng){
                sleep(8);
                mail($member['phone']."@vztext.com", "", $splitStrng, "From: Outage Notifications\r\n");

            }
        }
```

This code is unreliable.  sometimes I get a complete string of texts and sometimes one is lost in the middle.  Is there any way to send a complete string of texts reliably?

Comment: i think this dont work well because it will explode the words!! on 140 char maybe at the middle of a word!!!

Comment: that doesnt bother me necessarily.  it's just the fact i'm missing entire texts

Comment: read my comment again! i tried your code here!you loss your text because you explode the words!!

Comment: no.. i dont.  if I print $splitStrng out i will see all of my text.

Comment: use this `<pre><?php echo $splitStrng; ?></pre>` you will broke line brakes!!

Answer (score 0):

my solution 
first change line brakes to br

```
$text = nl2br($text);
```

**this is not required!but i see you will mail them at last!!

use explode with ' ' (space) to list all words!

```
$arr = explode(' ',$text);
```

then make your string again with adding array element to string and count each time you add other work

```
$final = '';
$messages = array();
foreach($arr as $ar){
          $final.=$ar;
          if(count($final)>140){
             $messages[] = $final;
             $final='';
          }
}
```